# socket.io in lb3app mounted app in lb4 (loopback)

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I have lb3app mounted in lb4 and everything work great except socket.io.

The socket.io initiated in the following function in the server.asp

```
    app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  app.emit('started');

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  /* if (require.main === module) { */
  // app.start();
  app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());
  app.io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
  app.io.socketIOConnectionCounter = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`total connections: ${app.io.engine.clientsCount}`);
  }, 1000 * 60);
  console.log('Socket.io started');
}
```

since it's mounted lb3app in lb4, i assume that i need to pass the lb4 app to this line:  `app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());` and not the lb3app as it is now. How can i do it? (Passing the app of the lb4 into that function and not the app of mounted lb3)?

Its important because if i leave it as is, lb3 starting the httpserer and the server is already because the app server already started by lb4 so the port already taken.

Thanks